# Merge cells Google sheets using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a script that would combine 3 columns in Google sheets when the script is running, The columns have headers:

First Name  Middle Name Last Name

My goal is that the Script would create a new column and have these combined with the whitespace removed if there is any extra.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1,B1,C1)
```

It joins texts from the cells A1, B1, C1 (no trim white spaces, though)

If you need a script here you go:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (let row in data) {
    var col1 = data[row][0].trim();           // First Name
    var col2 = data[row][1].trim();           // Middle Name
    var col3 = data[row][2].trim();           // Last Name
    var col4 = [col1, col2, col3].join(' ');  // combined full name
    data[row] = [col1, col2, col3, col4];
  }

  var table = [header, ...data];
  sheet.getRange(1,1,table.length,table[0].length).setValues(table);
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Another notation of the same algo, just in case:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var table = [header];

  while (data.length) {
    var row = data.shift().map(x => x.trim()).slice(0,-1);
    table.push([...row, row.join(' ')]);
  }
 
  sheet.getRange(1,1,table.length,table[0].length).setValues(table);
}
```